# Notepad++: Typing the "greater than" sign inside the already closed HTML tag auto-inserts another closing tag?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using the version 7.5.8 and I noticed that it auto-closes the already closed tag if I type the `>` sign in between.

E.g., if inside the body tag I type `ul>`(attempting to use the Emmet's syntax `ul>li`) I'll get this:

```
<body>

ul></body>

</body>
```

How do I prevent this annoying behavior? Is there any way to do so other than turning off the auto-completion feature completely?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the auto insertion of html/xml closing tags by going into 
Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion and unchecking "html/xml close tag" in the "Auto-Insert" section.

Comment: I didn't want to disable it completely initially, I (for some reason) was hoping there was a more elegant/sophisticated way of dealing with it. Thank you very much!